# Spark filter on dataframe with array containing a map

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe with schema which has a nested array of map values:

```
root
 |-- array_of_properties: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- props: map (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- key: string
 |    |    |    |-- value: string (valueContainsNull = true)
```

I need to filter on the struct name and some specific key's values in the map inside the array.  I can filter on the name:

```
dataframe.filter(array_contains(col("array_of_properties.name"), "somename"))
```

How do I add AND filters on values of two keys in the nested `props` map (for example a key name `is_enabled` with a boolean value of true or false, and a key name of `source` with a string value of `test`) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`exists`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/#exists) function:

```scala
dataframe.filter("exists(array_of_properties, x -> x.name = 'somename' and x.props['is_enabled'] is true)")
```

Comment: That works - thank you.  Are there any drawbacks to using an exists filter ?